# target.attr is not a function, length undefined jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two on click events for two different classes, they have one part of the code that is the same for both of them, so I tried making a function that would contain the part of the code which is the same, and then cal, that function inside onclick, but I keep getting one error.

This is the code that works properly:

```
$(list).on('click', function() {

    $(arrow).removeClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
    $(listItem).removeClass(listItem_expanded);
    $(list).addClass("mobile-select--sticky");
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if (target.length) {
      //prevent default bhebahvior
      event.preventDefault();
      var topDistance = target.offset().top;
      var bottomDistance = documentHeight - topDistance;
      if (windowHeight > bottomDistance) {
        $(container).css('padding-bottom', topDistance + 'px');
      };
      var stickyTopHeight = $(list).outerHeight();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - stickyTopHeight - 150
      }, 1000);
  
        if($(window).width() <= 769) {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - stickyTopHeight - 100
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    if($(window).width() <= 769) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass(list_expanded)) {
            $(this).addClass(list_expanded);
            $(arrow).addClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
            $(listItem).addClass(listItem_expanded);

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass(list_expanded);
            // $(this).slideUp();
            $(arrow).removeClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
            $(listItem).removeClass(listItem_expanded);
        }
    }
    if ($(window).width() > 769) {
        $(this).addClass(list_expanded);
        $(arrow).addClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
        $(listItem).addClass(listItem_expanded);
    }
    
});

$(link).on('click', function() {

    $(arrow).removeClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
    $(listItem).removeClass(listItem_expanded);
    $(list).addClass("mobile-select--sticky");
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); 
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if (target.length) {
        //prevent default bhebahvior
        event.preventDefault();
        var topDistance = target.offset().top;
        var bottomDistance = documentHeight - topDistance;
        if (windowHeight > bottomDistance) {
            $(container).css('padding-bottom', topDistance + 'px');
        }
        var stickyTopHeight = $(list).outerHeight();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - stickyTopHeight - 150
        }, 1000);
        if($(window).width() <= 769) {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - stickyTopHeight - 100
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

And this is what I tried doing but with zero luck, since I've been getting these errors: **Uncaught TypeError: target.attr is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

```
function doSomething(target) {
target = target || $(this);
$(arrow).removeClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
$(listItem).removeClass(listItem_expanded);
$(list).addClass("mobile-select--sticky");
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
if (target.attr('href').length) {
    //prevent default bhebahvior
    event.preventDefault();
    var topDistance = target.offset().top;
    var bottomDistance = documentHeight - topDistance;
    if (windowHeight > bottomDistance) {
        $(container).css('padding-bottom', topDistance + 'px');
    };
    var stickyTopHeight = $(list).outerHeight();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - stickyTopHeight - 150
    }, 1000);
    
    if($(window).width() <= 769) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - stickyTopHeight - 100
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

}

$(list).on('click', function() {
doSomething($(this));

```
if($(window).width() <= 769) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass(list_expanded)) {
        $(this).addClass(list_expanded);
        $(arrow).addClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
        $(listItem).addClass(listItem_expanded);
        
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass(list_expanded);
        // $(this).slideUp();
        $(arrow).removeClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
        $(listItem).removeClass(listItem_expanded);
    }
}
if ($(window).width() > 769) {
    $(this).addClass(list_expanded);
    $(arrow).addClass("mobile-select__arrow--active")
    $(listItem).addClass(listItem_expanded);
}
```

});

$(link).on('click', doSomething);

I just wanted to try and write these events in a shorter way. Is that possible?

Comment: `$(link).on('click', doSomething);` as an event handler is going to pass in the `event` to the method, not the target directly.  `function doSomething(event){ $(event.target).attr(...); }`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the one that's failing:

```
$(link).on('click', doSomething);
```

The `doSomething` function expects its one argument to be a jQuery object for a DOM element, but the `click` event passes the *event object*, not the element which invoked the event.  You can pass the element as a jQuery object the same way you do in your other `click` handler:

```
$(link).on('click', function () { doSomething($(this)); });
```

Comment: Depending upon what `link` is, with your second snippet that can be passed in, rather than using `this`, as an alternative.  Or just change the `doSomething` to get the target off of the event and avoid this extra wrapper method